# JMS Messaging between cross application deployed in same tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, messagebroker

I have two web application and deployed in same tomcat server. I want to send jms message from app1 to app2.

I created JMS connection factory and producer in app1 using spring jms (using embeded active mq broker url as vm://localhost)

But when I create the JMS client in app2, consumer is not able to receive messages.

How do I share same factory instance/queue in app2 web app? do I need to modify server.xml for sharing conn factory etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNDI to share the connection factory, just like you would with a JDBC (database) connection factory.

[ActiveMQ JNDI](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html)